# bootstrap navigation mobile drop down auto expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

ive rebuilt this twice now and this morning ive noticed that my bootstrap menu hamburger symbol to expand menu on mobile is now now showing and the menu is expanded, and reason for this ?

```
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand " href="<?php echo get_page_link(6); ?>"><img
                src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/logo.png"></a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right hidden-xs" style="margin-left: 10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</button>
</div>
<div id="navbar" style="background-color: #333;">
    <div class="container">
            <?php
            /* Primary navigation */
            wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'menu' => 'Primary Menu',
                    'theme_location' => 'locations-primary',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'exCollapsingNavbar2',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
            ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class "collapsed" (button) should be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
  </button>
```